# Hover results in bigger image, without moving text

Tags: css, image, hover, expand

I have the following file which I recreated on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3tt0hxo4/. The one big image (not the tiny one on top that is also a link) is the one I would love to be able to make bigger when I hover over it. Now I haven't tried anyting, but I'm pretty sure that if I do a simple comand that tells the image to be bigger when I hover it that this will then result in the text being moved around whcih is not what I want. I want the image to expand as if it was laying on top of the text, so the text would disappear (or almost all of it would disappear) and the image to just expand over it.

I tried to find out on google how to do it, but couldn't really find anything that would help me. I found one help forum post which said something about creating an invisible div that is floating on top of the text, but I was completely confused by that and the code that was given as an example didn't work when I tried to fit it to what I have. The code looked something like this

```
div#cover {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div#cover:hover {
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your fiddle.

```
#pic {
    background-color: #575c55; 
    z-index:1;
    border-width: 1; 
    border: solid;     
    text-align: left;
    width: auto; 
    height: 355px;
}

#pic img:hover {
    height: 355px;
    width:97%;
    margin:0 0;
    z-index:5; 
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
}
```

It selects the image on hover and makes it the full width and height of the div, placing it over top of the text.

Comment: This helps me a lot. It doesn't quite do what I want b/c the image size proportion is then screwed, but it basically gives me the right idea to go on experimenting. Thank you!

Comment: you could try using transform: scale(2,2); inside the hover selector instead of changing the hight/width.Unless you are using a large image I would change the image on hover to a larger version so it doesn't pixelate.